# Using a trained Model from Pickle

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, pickle

I trained and saved a model that should predict a sons hight based on his fathers height.
I then saved the model to Pickle.
I can now load the model and want to use it but unfortunately a second variable is demanded from me (besides the height of the father) I think I did something wrong when training the model?

I will post the part of the code wher I think the error is in, please ask if you need more.

```
#Spliting the data into test and train data
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

#Doing a linear regression
lm=LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train,y_train)

#testing the model with an example value
TestValue = 65.0
filename = 'Father_Son_Height_Model.pckl'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.predict(TestValue)
print(result)
```

The error message says:

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:

array=65.0.

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `loaded_model.predict(TestValue)`, not `loaded_model.score(TestValue)`. The latter is for evaluating the models accuracy, and you would also need to pass the true height of the son, which is the `y` value it's asking for.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, I changed it and the new error (edited in question) appears. Did I train the model wrong or something? Why is he expecting a array?

Comment: @G.M this is scikit-learn being a bit annoying. It needs an array _in a specific shape_ or it won't work. Try `loaded_model.predict(np.array(TestValue).reshape(-1, 1))`. skl is a great package but it could be more robust to this kind of thing. **Make sure to include `import numpy as np` somewhere**

Comment: Jesus Christ its working, i cant believe it :D I feel like Dr. Frankenstein now, thanks alot :D
I guess this isnt necessary when there is more then one arguement given for testing? so for example if I would have height of father and mother since it would be an arrray already.

Comment: @G.M You're welcome. Yeah exactly; normally you'd be predicting against an array of multiple rows   with multiple features and you'd not have hit that second error.

Comment: You right I think scikit learn should consider that, it may be rare in the real world but for a learner I would assume it is commen issue to run into. And given python it I would assume its easyly avoidable.... But who cares, I made a machine lerning thingy :D

Comment: lol, congratulations!